# Поиск неизвестной повторяющейся подстроки

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть длинная периодическая дробь по произвольному основанию, как найти её период? Т.е. найти повторяющуюся подстроку.

Comment: Вам нужно найти период именно десятичной дроби или подойдет решения для дроби вида N/M? Если второе то http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/teornum/findperiod.php

Comment: Десятичной, т.е. 0.8(3)

Answer (score 1):

Надо считать цифры с шагом 1 и шагом 2 одновременно. Когда остатки от деления совпадут, это будет означать, что ты находишься внутри периода. С этого мета просчитываешь ещё один цикл до получения того же остатка - так определяется длина периода.

Если нужно ещё минимальное начала периодической части, то считаешь заново две последовательности, одна из которых впереди на длину периода. Когда остатки совпадут, начало будет найдено.

В первой части можно вместо одновременного вычисления один раз промотать вперёд на длину заведомо большую длины предпериода (т. е. значение знаменателя).

Comment: Не много не подойдёт, я перевожу дробную часть числа в произвольную систему счисления и, например, 0.1 в двоичной периодическая дробь. Т.е. я умножают дробное число на основание системы, а не делю. Может мне поможет суффиксное дерево построить?

Comment: @user190370, подойдёт. Это подойдёт для любой периодической последовательности.

Comment: я не понимаю, на что делить? подробней можешь описать?

Comment: @user190370, ну дробь берёшь 1/10 и считаешь последовательно цифры.

Comment: т.е. я сравниваю остаток от деления первого числа(i=1) и остаток от деления следующего числа(i+1)?

Comment: @user190370, нет. Перечитай ответ - там вообще ничего о сравнении последовательных чисел нет.

Comment: Как считать цифры, не понимаю. Есть число (001010101010101) шаг1: 0%"число" шаг2:1%"число", так?