# Алгоритм поиска циклических зависимостей

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Задача:
В одномерном массиве, каждый элемент является индексом на элемент этого же массива. Найти и вывести индекс элементов, которые являются «зацикленными».
Пример: 
`a[0] = 7; a[1] = 3; a[2] = 1; a[3] = 2; a[4] = 0`

элементы `a[1]->a[3]->a[2]->a[1]` являются зацикленными.

Решение: не могу понять с чего начать. Если кто-то сможет привести пример и/или объяснить — будет прекрасно. 
Не могу сообразить условие, при котором будет проверятся наличие подобных «зацикленных» чисел.

Comment: Данный вопрос является совсем непонятным, неполным, слишком общим, основанным на личном мнении или не относится к теме Stack Overflow на русском как описано в Справке и вряд ли может быть улучшен правками.

Comment: Ну попытайтесь пройтись по ссылкам-индексам до тех пор, пока не наткнётесь на уже пройденный элемент. После чего ищите первый попавшийся непройденный элемент и повторяйте всё сначала от него до исчерпания.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461307/178988

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю почему так заминусовали вопрос. VladD по сути правильно ответил, но напишу более подробно. Надо завести массив bool used[n] (изначально все элементы false). Дальше идем по элементам массива и если элемент еще не использовался, значит запускаем внутренний цикл(но перед этим запомним индекс вот этого элемента с которого начнем): переходим в следующий элемент пока можем, отмечаем его в массиве used, если перешли в индекс стартового элемента - цикл найден.